# What is the best way to ignore eslint naming convention for aws-sdk library?

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-sdk, eslint

I am using `eslint` name convention to allow only camelCase for fields and attributes. But some parameters from `aws-sdk` library are using `pascal`. How can I ignore naming convention rules for all methods from `aws-sdk` library?

The rule I have is:

```
...
rules: {
    indent: ['error', 2],
    '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': 'error',
...
```

The code is:

```
import { DocumentClient } from 'aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb';
...
const params: DocumentClient.PutItemInput = {
      TableName: this.tableName,
      Item: {
        id
      },
    };
```

You can see that the `TableName` and `Item` is not camelCase which I'd like to ignore. But I don't want to ignore in each file. Is there a global way to ignore one library?